# mupen64plus not working; failed to find core library

Tags: uninstall, games, libraries, software-uninstall, emulation

Using Ubuntu 16.04LTS on an HP Beats 15 Notebook with 8 Gigs of RAM and an A10 AMD processor. I've never had this problem before while using mupen64plus on other computers with less RAM and less powerful processors, so I'm really at a loss as to what's going on here. I installed mupen64plus from the command line as always and when I try to run `mupen64plus <name of rom>` in the terminal this is what happens:

```
Mupen64Plus Console User-Interface Version 2.5.0

UI-Console Error: dlopen('/usr/local/lib/libmupen64plus.so.2') failed: 
libSDL-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
UI-Console Error: dlopen('./libmupen64plus.so.2') failed: 
./libmupen64plus.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
UI-Console Error: AttachCoreLib() Error: failed to find Mupen64Plus Core library
```

I then tried to install the M64.py front-end GUI to see if it would work that way, and still the same error message.

Finally, after running the command `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mupen64plus` to completely uninstall it and all of its dependencies, I'm still seeing the man pages for mupen64plus and the terminal still autocompletes the command `mupen64plus`.

This is the first time I've had this problem in 2 years of using mupen64plus--I've even gotten it to work well on a tiny HP Mini with no problems. What am I doing wrong here and how do I get it working right? What is causing this `failed to find core library` error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from */usr/local/lib/libmupen64plus.so.2* path.
It seems that you have two installation of the application - in */usr/local* and in normal paths (as the the result of the installation of deb-package).

Remove such file(s) with

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libmupen64plus.so.2
```

Also check the contents of */usr/local/share/man/* path.

---

If you need to have mupen64plus installed you can reinstall [official Ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/mupen64plus-ui-console) with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mupen64plus-ui-console
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and reinstalled and now it doesn't crash but it still doesn't work:

Comment: It just hangs on the following: `Core Warning: No video plugin attached.  There will be no video output.
Core Warning: No RSP plugin attached.  The video output will be corrupted.
Core Warning: No audio plugin attached.  There will be no sound output.
Core Warning: No input plugin attached.  You won't be able to control the game.
Core Warning: OpenGL function glActiveTexture() not supported.  OSD deactivated.
Core: Starting R4300 emulator: Dynamic Recompiler
Core: R4300: starting 64-bit dynamic recompiler at: 0x7f561d55b6e0`

Comment: Okay after reinstalling the M64py front-end GUI in addition to your above advice the emulator is working now! May the Source be with you!